# TEXTJOIN with IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, textjoin

I need assistance with my TEXTJOIN with an array IF statement.
Here is what I'm working with:

=TEXTJOIN(" | ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$9=$D2,$B$2:$B$9,"None"))

I'm trying to pull in all of the "Condition" in the left table with the matching "NCT ID" in the right table, with " | " as the delimiter. For some reason, my formula above is returning what you see below. What am I missing?
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ypUC.png)]
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mTNk.jpg)]

I tried: =TEXTJOIN(" | ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$9=$D2,$B$2:$B$9,"None"))

But, the formula is returning conditions that do not match the condition.